# Multi Binding In Dagger2 with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

So, I have this issue which I think I understand what's happening but I don't know a way out.
Note: I'm pretty new to Dagger 2 ...I'm coming from SpringBoot and it pretty lazy out there, so take it easy on me.

> I have a module that provides three methods, the last method depends on the first two methods like below:

```
@Module
class CoreModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("appName")
    fun appName() : String{
        return "Uburu Store"
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("appVersion")
    fun appVersion() : String {
        return "0.0.1"
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("appInfo")
    fun appInfo(appName: String, appVersion: String) : String {
        return "$appName Version:: $appVersion"
    }
}
```

> I'm getting an error that:

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
```

> My ApplicationComponent class:

```
@Component(modules = [(CoreModule::class), (AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class), (ActivityBuildersModule::class)])
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<ApplicationClass> {

    fun inject(application: Application)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application?): Builder?

        fun build(): ApplicationComponent?
    }

}
```

> My activity class:

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject @Named("appInfo") lateinit var appInfo : String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Toast.makeText(this, appInfo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

> I managed to make it work if I don't use @Named annotation in any of the two dependencies i.e if I delete one of the Two provided dependencies from CoreModule, and remove the @Named annotation from the only dependency left, it will work fine like below:

```
    @Module
    class CoreModule {
    
        @Provides
        fun appName() : String{
            return "Uburu Store"
        }
    
        @Provides
        @Named("appInfo")
        fun appInfo(appName: String) : String {
            return "$appName Version:: $"
        }
    
    }
//This will work just fine, which made me realize that the @Named must be making it difficult for Dagger to understand something.
```

The problem with this approach is that I can't do without the @Named as it's needed for Multiple Binding of the same DataTypes e.g: String.

> My research so far made it known to me that I have to use @JvmSuppressWildcards somewhere but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dagger provides a dependency based on class types in the graph, in your first code snippet of CoreModule it fails to provide dependencies into the `appInfo(String, String)` method because it cannot figure out which String type belongs where. The fix is simple; annotate the dependencies that you have already provided with the `@Named` qualifier in the method that requires them within the module:

```
@Module
class CoreModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("appName")
    fun appName() : String{
        return "Uburu Store"
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("appVersion")
    fun appVersion() : String {
        return "0.0.1"
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("appInfo")
    fun appInfo(@Named("appName") appName: String, @Named("appVersion") appVersion: String) : String {
        return "$appName Version:: $appVersion"
    }
}
```

Your second example works because there is only one String type to be provided from the graph.

For more information head over to the [documentation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/) and scroll to Qualifier section

Comment: Thank you @Droid , I was busy doing (@)Inject in place of (@)Named like above which wasn't allowed.
I'm good now, it worked.
Using (@) because of StackOverflow annotation clash. lol.